# Left-justifying fixed-width table column

Tags: alignment, text

I have a table containing three columns. I would like to left-align the rightmost column (which is justified now), but for some reason, adding \raggedright gives me an error. This is my code (without the \raggedright addition):

```
\documentclass[conference,compsoc]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!h]
\caption{abc}
    \label{xyz}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{p{0.11\linewidth} p{0.5\linewidth} p{0.24\linewidth}}
        \toprule
        \textbf{Model} & \textbf{Description} & \textbf{Implementation}\\
        \cmidrule[0.4pt]{1-3}
        a & \ldots & Voluptas vel consequatur laborum ea atque et dicta qui. Veniam est rem in nulla sint omnis tempore. Ipsam velit cum aliquam atque culpa sint. \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You don't need to add \raggedright: p{...}  columns are in paragraph mode, hence  justified. Could you explain what the concrete problem is?

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for being unclear, I mixed up the terms. I want the text to be left-aligned, but now it is indeed justified (a "block"). I will edit my question accordingly.

Comment: In short, you do not want hyphenation in the last column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need add also a `\arraybackslash`, but for columns with a lot of text and different alignments, where one must find with trial and errors the best width for each one, `tabulary` package could be a better alternative:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[conference,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabulary}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!h]
\caption{abc}
    \label{xyz}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{p{0.11\linewidth} p{0.5\linewidth}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.24\linewidth}}
        \toprule
        \textbf{Model} & \textbf{Description} & \textbf{Implementation}\\
        \cmidrule[0.4pt]{1-3}
        a & \ldots & Voluptas vel consequatur laborum ea atque et dicta qui. Veniam est rem in nulla sint omnis tempore. Ipsam velit cum aliquam atque culpa sint. \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h]
\caption{abc}
\centering
\setlength\tabcolsep{.8em}
\begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{@{}lRCL@{}}\toprule
\textbf{Model} & \textbf{Description} &  \textbf{Description} & \textbf{Description}\\\midrule
 a & 
Voluptas vel consequatur laborum ea atque et dicta qui. Veniam est rem in nulla sint omnis tempore. 
Ipsam velit cum aliquam atque culpa sint. &
Voluptas vel consequatur laborum ea atque et dicta qui. Veniam est rem in nulla sint omnis tempore. 
Ipsam velit cum aliquam atque culpa sint. &
Voluptas vel consequatur laborum ea atque et dicta qui. Veniam est rem in nulla sint omnis tempore. 
Ipsam velit cum aliquam atque culpa sint. \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabulary}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h]
\caption{abc}
\centering
\setlength\tabcolsep{.8em}
\begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{@{}lLL@{}}\toprule
\textbf{Model} & \textbf{Description} &  \textbf{Description}\\\midrule
 a & 
Voluptas vel consequatur laborum ea atque et dicta qui. Veniam est rem in nulla sint omnis tempore. 
Ipsam velit cum aliquam atque culpa sint. Voluptas vel consequatur laborum ea atque et dicta qui. Veniam est rem in nulla sint omnis tempore. 
Ipsam velit cum aliquam atque culpa sint. &
Voluptas vel consequatur laborum ea atque et dicta qui. Veniam est rem in nulla sint omnis tempore. 
Ipsam velit cum aliquam atque culpa sint. \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabulary}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! This was the fix.